# How to randomize uıcollecitonview cells when "pull to refresh" like Instagram Explore page

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift4, instagram

I have a page that contains uicollectionview cells sorted by date. 
I work on swift 4.2 and want this page to work like the Explore page on instagram. 
So when user pull to refresh, collectionview cells will be sorted by randomly.
How can I develop this function ?

Answer (score 0):

Randomize the contents of the datasource that you're using for your collection and then `collectionView.reloadData()`. I think that should work.